# Get data.sql back from data of the H2 database to use in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

As the title says, how can I get the data from the h2-database to data.sql in spring boot? I managed to get the whole sql with adding all the tables and stuff, but thats not in the format that hibernate uses.

Here is how the data.sql looks like when it is running

```
insert into korisnik(id, email, ime, prezime, lozinka, uloga, fresh, enabled) values (1, 'stefan.colic4@gmail.com', 'Stefan', 'Colic', 'Bar5slova', 5, false, false)
```

How can I  get data like that from the classic sql i get from H2?

Comment: If I understand right, you meant to run **select** queries in data.sql like `select email from korisnik where id =1`